# contract pallet installation issues

Tags: pallet-contracts

A few months back, I added contract-pallet to the Polkadot using the [link](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/pallet-design/add-contracts-pallet/). At that time, I used Polkadot 0.9.28 as the node version. There was another link from the substrate that uas also [useful](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/contracts-pallet/).

At this point, both links are missing from the substrate page.
Does it mean that the present versions have the contract-pallet enabled by default?

If not enabled by default, how to get the contract-pallet enabled in Polkadot?
Are any tutorials or links available for Polkadot 0.9.40 to enable contract-pallet?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean the tutorial where `pallet-contracts` was added to the `substrate-node-template`. This tutorial is indeed removed.

You can use [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node) where you have a node-template with `pallet-contracts`.

Additional info (after comment): cargo contract uses JSON-RPC to interact with the contracts node template ([see ink docs](https://use.ink/getting-started/calling-your-contract)):

```
cargo contract build
cargo contract upload --suri //Alice
cargo contract instantiate --suri //Alice --args ...
cargo contract call --contract ... --message get --dry-run --suri //Alice
```

[image]

Comment: This is for running the contract node interface. If you want to connect the RPC method ( accessing using the nodeJS interface), I cannot go with this method.  One needs to connect to the polkadot.js.org interface to instantiate the contract and use it in a framework. Substrate-contact-node is for testing purposes only.

Comment: See edit @StanlyWilson

Comment: I don't see any problem with the above answer.
Please refer to https://use.ink/ for checking how to prepare a node where you can deploy your smart contracts.

In the above documentation you will also find the different options when it comes to the deployment itself, contracts-UI or cargo-contracts being the main ones.